# Using Math.cos() to find cosine of angle in degrees

Tags: java, math

I want to give the result the Math.cos() method in java in degrees.I have tried methods like converting from radians to degrees. But I discovered that any number I pass into the Math.cos() method is being treated as radians,irrespective of whether I convert.Please I can I make it give me the result in degrees.Thanks.

Comment: Show what you have tried...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I discovered that any number I pass into the `Math.cos()` method is being treated as radians, irrespective of whether I convert.

The discovery is quite correct, and is precisely why you convert. Once you've done the conversion, you pass the resultant angle (which is in radians) to `Math.cos()`, and everyone is happy.

Comment: Use Math.toRadians to convert

Answer (score 12):

use Math.toRadians to convert your degrees to radians to pass to Math.cos
for example

```
double blah = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(50));
```

I think that is what you are asking.  There are quite a lot of similar questions here.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Math.toDegrees()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toDegrees%28double%29)/[Math.toRadians()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toRadians%28double%29)

> Converts an angle measured in radians to an approximately equivalent
>   angle measured in degrees/radians.

Note that [public static double cos(double a)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#cos%28double%29) expect the parameter in radians:

> a - an angle, in radians.